# Change Action of Contact Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a Contact form that has a drop down with options, now I need depending on the option the person clicks on from the drop down, The name of the "Action" on Contact form to change, that way I can assign a different PHP FILE depending on there option. I know what I want im just having a hard time coding this to make it work. I'll provide the html form and the PHP below.

---

```html
<div id="form123">
<form id="my-form" action="sitephp.php" method="post">
  <table width="343" border="0" align="center">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
```

---

```html
       <select name="Machine" required id="Machine" onChange="changeSelectValue();">
              <option selected="selected"></option>
              <option id="machine 1" value="sitephp1.php">machine 1</option>
<option value="sitephp2.php">machine 2</option>
<option id="machine 3" value="sitephp3.php">machine 3 </option>
            </select>
```

---

```html
<script type="text/javascript" >
function changeSelectValue() {
    var myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');
    var selectValue = document.querySelector('#Machine').value;
    var actionFile = '';
    switch (selectValue) {
        case 'machine 1':
            actionFile = 'sitephp1.php';
            break;
        case 'machine 2':
            actionFile = 'sitephp2.php';
            break;
        case 'machine 3':
            actionFile = 'sitephp3.php';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    } 
    myForm.setAttribute('action', actionFile);
}
</script>
```

---

```html
<?php
$email1=$_POST['Email1'];
$email2=$_POST['Email2'];
$from=$_POST['Email1'];
$email='YOUR EMAIL HERE';
$subject=" Request ";
$message=$_POST['Box'];
$machine=$_POST['Machine'];
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$number=$_POST['Number'];
$message="Name: ".$name."\r\n"."Phone: ".$phone."\r\n"."Email: " .$from ."\r\n"."Machine: ".$machine."\r\n"."Problem:  ".$message ;

if ($number !=10) {
    die("You are not a human! or your answer was incorrect!, Please go back and try again.");
}

if(!filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Invalid email ($email1)");
}
if ($email1 == $email2) {
    mail ($email, $subject, $message, "from:".$from);
    echo 'Thanks You for the Maintenance Request! We will Contact you shortly. ';
}
else {
    echo "This ($email2) email address is different from ($email1).\n";
}

?>
```

---

Comment: Instead of using several files - use __one__ but check `select` value in it and action accrodingly.

Comment: Your question is not clear, do you mean that when user will change the option of machine you want to change action="ACTION.PHP" to another php file?

Comment: yes, that is correct @Mhd.Jarkas sorry for the confusion i didn't know how to explain this very well.

Comment: The best option to do that by using jquery and change the value based on user choose

Comment: @Mhd.Jarkas I would have to give each option a value? for example            <option value="action.php">machine 1</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a function bind to the onchange of your select as below:

```
<select name="Select" required id="Select" onchange="changeSelectValue();">
```

Add an id to your form:

```
<form id="my-form" action="sitephp.php" method="post">
```

Use the following JS code to change your action property depending on the selected value:

```
function changeSelectValue() {
    var myForm = document.querySelector('#my-form');
    var selectValue = document.querySelector('#Select').value;
    if (selectValue.length > 0) {
        myForm.setAttribute('action', selectValue);
    } 
}
```

Just change the `file1.php`, `file2.php` and `file3.php` with your files.

If you don't have a JS file attached to the page, wrap the above JS code inside a `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` and place it at the end of the page before the body end tag.

P.S. Now you changed your code putting the name of the file to call directly inside the value of the options. In this way you don't need anymore the switch case, and you can directly use the value of the select as the action attribute of the form to use.

Comment: i made the changes but when i hit submit i get directed too "/FILE-NAME"?

Comment: this code is an example code: `myForm.setAttribute('action', 'FILE-NAME');`

You have to change FILE-NAME with the name that you want to use depending on the `selectValue` variable, which stores the value you selected by the select... I gave it as assumption that you should change that code.... did you get what I mean?
Changing the code in order to explain you better what I mean.
p.s. EDITED

Comment: does that mean then that i would have to copy and paste for each option and change the "actionFile" part to its value? sorry if im being annoying i just quit understand javascript to well } 
    myForm.setAttribute('action', actionFile);
}

Comment: changing again the example completing for all the cases...you just have to change the file1.php, file2.php, file3.php with your three file names.
Edited.

Comment: i updayed my html and php with specifications that you sent me but when i test i do a test, the receivers aren't receiving anything it's not being sent is there something i missed?

Comment: Do you have the three files 'file1.php', 'file2.php', 'file3.php' correctly defined in the same folder of your html file?

Comment: my file name is sitephp.php so  actionFile = 'sitephp.php'; would be correct?

Comment: You said that you want to direct requests to three files right?
So create this three files, call them 'sitephp1.php', 'sitephp2.php' and 'sitephp3.php'.
Keep your 'sitephp.com' as default one.
Now copy the new sections that I am updating in the answer above in order to use these files

Comment: Edited. 
Now by default you send the request to the sitephp.php
If you select the item 1 in the dropdown you send the request to the sitephp1.php and so on...

Comment: I made the changes from the edit, I have 4 php files, sitephp.php, sitephp1.php, sitephp2.php, sitephp3.php. when I fill in the contact and select the option and hit submit it doesn't work, it looks like the page refreshes I check my emails and theirs nothing, note: all the PHP files are the same the only thing that changes is the email of who's going to receive the information.  p.s. i've edited my html , Java ,PHP above so it would be easier for you to see my changes. also i noticed in your Javascript " var actionFile =' '; " the actionFile is = to nothing.

Comment: you changed the value of the select's options to the wrong ones. You should put back your values as they were before, or update my switch case in JavaScript. I am changing again the code in order to match with your changes. p.s. your php files have to be in the same folder of the HTML one

Comment: changed the code to match your changes. Added explanation of why it was not working with your new changes at the end of the answer

Comment: Perfect its working, there being sent to the different emails. you've really helped me out! thank you so much and i apologize if i was being hard to work with, im not not the best when it comes to JS. when i receive the email and i read the contact form, where it says "machine:" its showing me the value of the option instead of wording.                                         Name: Fake Name
Phone: 777-777-7777
Email: youremail@email.com
Machine: sitephp2.php
Problem:  2

Comment: Yeah that's because you changed the value of the options using the filename for that. If you change back the value you need to put back the switch case in order to use the right file associated to the right value

Comment: ohhhh, okay well thank you so much and for your patients I really appreciate the help! @quirimmo

Comment: You are welcome :) I think you can't vote yet, but can you anyway vote up my answer please? new to stackoverflow and trying to build a reputation! Thanks and good luck for your web application!

Comment: ill try but i don't think stack overflow lets me but i was wondering, as to how did you find my question and how did you learn java script if you don't mind me asking, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to have one main `*.php` script where you choose a further course of events that depends on the user's input, for example:

```
switch ( $_POST['Machine'] ) {
    case 0:
        include 'script1.php';
        break;
    case 1:
        include 'script2.php';
        break;
    case 2:
        include 'script3.php';
        break;
}
```

Comment: Add action to form, like `action="contact.php"`, create new file `contact.php` and paste the code above. Add values to options, `value="1"`, `value="2"`, etc. And of course, rename the `'script1.php'`, `'script1.php'`, etc. to match your `.php` files. I do not recommend using javascript for this problem.